# Cannot read CPU temperature with HWMonitor

Tags: motherboard, cooling, temperature

I bought a new MoBo and a FX4300 Black Edition along with a tower cooler. In the Monitor of my Mobo it says around 29° C (that's believable).

Looking at HWMonitor, my CPU has a temperature of about 10-20° C. It even goes below 10° sometimes. (Seems to be too good to be true.)

Why is HWMonitor reporting such low temperatures?

> CPU: AMD FX4300
>
> MoBo: [ASUS M5A78L-M](http://www.asus.com/Motherboards/M5A78LMUSB3/)
>
> Cooler: [Katana Tower Cooler](http://www.scythe-eu.com/en/products/cpu-cooler/katana-4.html)

[image: Screenshot of HWMonitor]

Sidenote: When I had an AMD 965, I was able to read temperature per core. Is this normal for FX Processors to only have 1 reading for the CPU?

Comment: Have you installed all the drivers for your motherboard? Have you tried running HWMonitor with Administrative privileges?

Comment: Yes all drivers are installed, HWMonitor runs as admin by default.